# Shopify liquid forloop.last of a certain block type

Tags: for-loop, shopify, liquid

I have two `for` loops looking at blocks within a section and I am using an `if` statement to check the block type each time. I want to show a `hr` to separate each block of each type, unless its the last block where I don't want the `hr` to show.

I thought using `forloop.last` would work but for some reason, the `forloop.last` check is only working on the second loop. It seems the initial loop is not closing or the `forloop.last` is not picking up on the `if` statement for block type. Example code below:

```
{% if section.settings.productaccordion_active %}
      <ul class="product-accordion  product-accordion-small">
          {% if section.settings.accordion_description_active %}
            <li id="product-accordion-1">
              <div class="product-accordion-title">Description</div>
              <div class="product-accordion-content">
                {%- for block in section.blocks -%}
                  {% if block.type == "accordion_description" %}
                    {% if block.settings.accordion_description_title %}
                      <h5>{{ block.settings.accordion_description_title }}</h5>
                      {{ block.settings.accordion_description_content }}
                    {% endif %}
                    {% unless forloop.last %}
                      <hr>
                    {% endunless %}
                  {% endif %}
                {%- endfor -%}
              </div>
            </li>
          {% endif %}

          {% if section.settings.accordion_ingredients_active  %}
            <li id="product-accordion-2">
              <div class="product-accordion-title">Ingredients</div>
              <div class="product-accordion-content">
                  {%- for block in section.blocks -%}
                      {% if block.type == "accordion_ingredients" %}
                        {% if block.settings.accordion_ingredients_title %}
                          <h5>{{ block.settings.accordion_ingredients_title }}</h5>
                          {{ block.settings.accordion_ingredients_content }}
                          <br><span class="product-popup-link" data-popupid="popup_ingredient_A_breakdown">See breakdown</span>
                          <br><span class="product-popup-link" data-popupid="popup_ingredient_A_full">See full list</span>
                        {% endif %}
                        {% unless forloop.last %}
                          <hr>
                        {% endunless %}
                      {% endif %}
                  {%- endfor -%}
              </div>
            </li>
          {% endif %}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Blair, if possible can I have your complete file code with the schema so that I can test the code on my side? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The forloop.last condition cannot be fulfilled for each loop because you add an if condition. So if the last item in the loop is not of the type you display, then `<hr>` will never be displayed.

Here is something that should work (not tested).

First, you create two arrays containing only blocks with needed types.

```
{% liquid
   assign description_blocks = section.blocks | where: "type", "accordion_description" 
   assign ingredient_blocks = section.blocks | where: "type", "accordion_ingredients"
%}
```

Then you loop through each array defined above.
This way, for each one, it will always iterate the last item of the loop.

```
<ul class="product-accordion  product-accordion-small">

    {% if section.settings.accordion_description_active %}
        <li id="product-accordion-1">
            {%- for block in description_blocks -%}
                Do something
                {% unless forloop.last %}
                    <hr>
                {% endunless %}
            {%- endfor -%}
        </li>
     {% endif %}
    
     {% if section.settings.accordion_ingredients_active  %}
         <li id="product-accordion-2">
             {%- for block in ingredient_blocks -%}
                 Do something
                 {% unless forloop.last %}
                     <hr>
                 {% endunless %}
              {%- endfor -%}
          </li>
      {% endif %}

</ul>
```

Here is some documentation about the where filter:

https://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/where/

HTH